# Multiselect css not refreshing after Ajax call returning PartialView

Tags: css, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying doing an ajax call that replaces a div, but my multiselect controls are losing its styling.

I have a view that is calling my partial view:

```
@Html.Partial("_Languages",Model)
```

In this view I also have a reference to the `unobstrusive-ajax.min.js` file and the related css:

```
<link href="~/SmartAdmin/scripts/Test/css/bootstrap-multiselect.css" rel="stylesheet" /> //This is a the top of my view
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script> //This is at the bottom of my view
```

I have a scripts file that is referencing to the `jquery` and `jquery-ui` files which is being called from my Layout page.

In my partial view I am using `Ajax.BeginForm` with its options to replace the "listofLanguages" div:

```
@model AccountRegistrationModel


<div id="listofLanguages">
    <article class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-6">
        <!-- Widget ID (each widget will need unique ID)-->
        <div class="jarviswidget jarviswidget-color-darken" id="wid-id-0" data-widget-editbutton="false" data-widget-deletebutton="false" data-widget-togglebutton="false">
            <!-- widget options:
            usage: <div class="jarviswidget" id="wid-id-0" data-widget-editbutton="false">

            data-widget-colorbutton="false"
            data-widget-editbutton="false"
            data-widget-togglebutton="false"
            data-widget-deletebutton="false"
            data-widget-fullscreenbutton="false"
            data-widget-custombutton="false"
            data-widget-collapsed="true"
            data-widget-sortable="false"

            -->
            <header>
                <span class="widget-icon"> <i class="fa fa-table"></i> </span>
                <h2>Languages </h2>

            </header>

            <!-- widget div-->
            <div>

                <!-- widget edit box -->
                <div class="jarviswidget-editbox">
                    <!-- This area used as dropdown edit box -->

                </div>
                <!-- end widget edit box -->
                <!-- widget content -->

                <div class="widget-body no-padding">
                    <div class="widget-body no-padding">
                        @{
                            var options = new AjaxOptions()
                            {
                                //LoadingElementId = "loadingDisplay",
                                HttpMethod = "POST",
                                InsertionMode = InsertionMode.ReplaceWith,
                                UpdateTargetId = "listofLanguages"
                                //OnBegin = "ChangeButtonText"
                            };
                        }
                        @using (Ajax.BeginForm("SaveLanguage", "Account", options, new { @id = "ppl", @class = "smart-form" }))
                        {
                            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.UserId)
                            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Email)
                            TempData["email"] = Model.Email;
                            <fieldset>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <section class="col col-6">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <select id="Language" name="Language" style="width:100%" class="select2" value="@Model.Language">
                                                @foreach (var languagemetro in @Model.LanguageMetrosList)
                                                {
                                                    <optgroup label="@languagemetro.LanguageMetroName">
                                                        @foreach (var language in Model.LanguageList)
                                                        {
                                                            if (@languagemetro.pkiLanguageMetroID == @language.fkiLanguageMetroId)
                                                            {
                                                                if (@language.Language == Model.Language)
                                                                {
                                                                    <option value="@language.Language" selected="selected">@language.Language</option>

                                                                }
                                                                else
                                                                {
                                                                    <option value="@language.Language">@language.Language</option>
                                                                }

                                                            }
                                                        }
                                                    </optgroup>
                                                }
                                            </select>
                                        </div>
                                    </section>
                                    <section class="col col-6">
                                        <select id="ddlReadWriteSpeak" name="SelectedReadWriteSpeak" multiple="multiple">
                                            <option value="Read">Read</option>
                                            <option value="Write">Write</option>
                                            <option value="Speak">Speak</option>
                                        </select>
                                        <br />
                                        <br />
                                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-xs pull-right">
                                            Save Language
                                        </button>
                                        @*<div class="pull-right">
                                                @Html.ActionLink("Save Language", "SaveLanguage", "Account", new { userEmail = Model.Email, iLanguageId = $('Languages').val() }, new { @class = "btn btn-success btn-xs" })
                                            </div>*@
                                    </section>

                                </div>

                            </fieldset>
                        }
                    </div>

                    <table id="dt_basic" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" width="100%">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th style="width:5%"></th>
                                <th data-class="expand"><i class="text-muted hidden-md hidden-sm hidden-xs"></i> Language</th>
                                <th data-hide="phone" style="text-align:center"><i class="text-muted hidden-md hidden-sm hidden-xs"></i> Read</th>
                                <th data-hide="phone,tablet" style="text-align:center"><i class="txt-color-blue hidden-md hidden-sm hidden-xs"></i> Write</th>
                                <th data-hide="phone,tablet" style="text-align:center"><i class="txt-color-blue hidden-md hidden-sm hidden-xs"></i> Speak</th>
                                <th></th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>

                            @{
                                int a = 0;

                                foreach (var item in Model.LanguagesViewModelList.OrderBy(x => x.PriorityLevel))
                                {
                                    a++;
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            @if (a == Model.LanguagesViewModelList.Count())
                                            {
                                                <a href="@Url.Action("LanguagePriorityUp", new { pkiRes_LanguageId=item.Res_LanguageId })">
                                                    <span class="fa fa-toggle-up"></span>
                                                </a>

                                            }
                                            else if (item.PriorityLevel > 1)
                                            {
                                                <a href="@Url.Action("LanguagePriorityUp", new { pkiRes_LanguageId=item.Res_LanguageId })">
                                                    <span class="fa fa-toggle-up"></span>
                                                </a>
                                                <a href="@Url.Action("LanguagePriorityDown", new { pkiRes_LanguageId=item.Res_LanguageId })">
                                                    <span class="fa fa-toggle-down"></span>
                                                </a>
                                            }
                                            else if (item.PriorityLevel == 1)
                                            {
                                                <a href="@Url.Action("LanguagePriorityDown", new { pkiRes_LanguageId=item.Res_LanguageId })">
                                                    <span class="fa fa-toggle-down"></span>
                                                </a>
                                            }
                                        </td>
                                        <td>@item.Language</td>
                                        <td style="text-align:center">
                                            @if (item.Read == "Yes")
                                            {
                                                <span class="fa fa-check"></span>
                                            }
                                            else
                                            {
                                                <span class="fa fa-close"></span>
                                            }
                                        </td>
                                        <td style="text-align:center">
                                            @if (item.Write == "Yes")
                                            {
                                                <span class="fa fa-check"></span>
                                            }
                                            else
                                            {
                                                <span class="fa fa-close"></span>
                                            }
                                        </td>
                                        <td style="text-align:center">
                                            @if (item.Speak == "Yes")
                                            {
                                                <span class="fa fa-check"></span>
                                            }
                                            else
                                            {
                                                <span class="fa fa-close"></span>
                                            }
                                        </td>
                                        <td>

                                            @*<a href="#" id="dialog_link" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs">
                                                    <span class="fa fa-trash-o"></span>
                                                </a>*@
                                            <a href="@Url.Action("DeleteLanguage", new { pkiRes_LanguageId = item.Res_LanguageId })">
                                                <span class="fa fa-trash-o"></span>
                                            </a>

                                            @*@Html.ActionLink("Delete","Delete", new { employmentId = item.pkiEmploymentDetailID, userId = Model.fkiUserID })*@
                                            @*<button type="submit" onclick="deleteEmployment('@item.pkiEmploymentDetailID')" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger text-center">
                                                    <span class="fa fa-trash-o"></span>&nbsp;
                                                </button>*@
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                }
                            }

                        </tbody>
                    </table>

                </div>
                <!-- end widget content -->

            </div>
            <!-- end widget div -->

        </div>
        <!-- end widget -->
    </article>

</div>
```

What am I missing that my multiselect controls are not pulling through the css ?

**EDIT**
So using firefox and looking in the console log, it didnt show anything, but using chrome I got this error :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined
```

I am suspecting it is because my multi-select.js file is not being pulled through after the ajax call, but I have no idea how to include it after the ajax call ?

If I am leaving out any information, please let me know.

Comment: refer to this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20401703/bootstrap-multiselect-update-option-list-on-flow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I couldnt find a solution to this specific issue, the multiselects just never refreshed. I even tried the destroy attribute, nothing worked.

What I ended up doing is leaving the mutiselects in the view and the partial view contained my table and I just refreshed the table in the partial view.