# Update multiple dropdown value with checkbox on change of another dropdown using AJAX in PHP

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I want to update multiple dropdown value on change of another dropdown using AJAX in my project.

Suppose I have some `services` under `treatment` table.
For `treatment A` services are `A1,A2,A3`, `treatment B` services are `B1,B2,B3`.

when I choose `treatment A` from dropdown list another dropdown list is auto updated with the value `A1,A2,A3`...when choose `treatment B` from dropdown list another dropdown list is auto updated with the value `B1,B2,B3`.

while I use

```
<select id="department_id_appointment" multiple="multiple">
@if($_SESSION['department'] != null)

    @foreach($_SESSION['department'] as $data)

        <option value="{{ $data->id }}">{{ $data->name }}</option>

    @endforeach

@endif
```

Data is shown correctly

[image]

But while I want to update the service dropdown value using AJAX it shows nothing though the values is shown in `console log`.

[image]

Here is my AJAX code

```
$.ajax({

url:"{{ url('/filter_service') }}",
type: 'GET',
data: {_token :token, department_id : department_id, branch : branch},
success:function(msg){



    $('#service_id_appointment option').remove();

    trHTML = '';

    msg.forEach(function(item){

        trHTML += "<option value='"+item.id+"'>" + item.name + "</option>";
    });

    $('#service_id_appointment').append(trHTML);

    console.log(trHTML);
}
```

});

HTML where want to update the dropdown

```
<div class="gaps" id="select_multiple_service_id">
<p>Service</p>

<select id="service_id_appointment" multiple="multiple">

</select>

<div id="service_id_message" class="val_error"></div>
```

Here is the returning data show in console

[image]

Comment: Is your ajax returning anything?

Comment: yes it's return the values which is shown in the consol...but not shown in the frontend dropdown

Comment: if it returns what you want or expect, then it's most likely a javascript / jquery problem..

Comment: yes... can't find the solution yet....

Comment: Might be useful to see what gets returned to the js in `msg` can you show us that. Or the PHP code that generates the returned values

Comment: @ RiggsFolly...yes I have updated my post...please check

Comment: So you are just returning a string, not a json array or anything?

Comment: @Naruto...yes..

Comment: You are returning raw HTML so all you need to do is replace the existing select with the new html

Comment: @ RiggsFolly....Sorry I have return json format....update the post...

Comment: @Naruto.....sorry I have given the wrong picture. Now I have updated the post with JSON value

Comment: Could you past some of the actual json response into the question instead of a screenshot please?

Comment: @cfreear....Here is a json value....
`0
:
{id: 8, name: "demo1"}
1
:
{id: 19, name: "Memory loss"}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the solution !!

Just add the below code after loading all the data

`$('#service_id_appointment').multiselect('rebuild')`

Cause  after loading all the data we need to call the `mulselect()` function again to make multiple dropdown checkbox.

Here is the full Ajax code

```
$.ajax({

url:"{{ url('/filter_service') }}",
type: 'GET',
data: {_token :token, department_id : department_id, branch : branch},

success:function(msg){

    $('#service_id_appointment option').remove();

    trHTML = '';

    msg.forEach(function(item){

        trHTML += "<option value='"+item.id+"'>" + item.name + "</option>";
    });

    $('#service_id_appointment').append(trHTML);

    $('#service_id_appointment').multiselect('rebuild') //----add this line----
}
```

});

For more details
[Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20401703/bootstrap-multiselect-update-option-list-on-flow)